# Checking significance of variable within each category in regression

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, interaction

I have data with 3 columns: `y` represents dependent continuous variable, `xcont` represents independent continuous variable, `xcat` represents independent categorical variable with 3 levels: `xcat1`, `xcat2`, and `xcat3`.
I am doing simple model with interaction:

```
y = xcont + xcat + xcon*xcat
```

The results show that `xcat1` and `xcat2` are significant and positive (`xcat3` is used as a base level). So, I can conclude that `xcat1` is significantly higher than `xcat3` and `xcat2` is also significantly higher than `xcat3`.

Now, coefficient for `xcat1` is higher than coefficient for `xcat2`. What test should I look into to check that `xcat1` is *significantly* higher than `xcat2`? Right now I am thinking about switching a base category. Say, I pick `xcat1`. Then I will have my answer of whether `xcat2` is significantly different from `xcat2`. But I thought maybe there is another way.

Also, will it be an issue that I have an interaction there?